# powershell script to create an incremental backup

Tags: powershell, windows-server

I'm trying to create an incremental backup for windows server using powershell to backup my documents folder every monday,tuesday,thursday,friday, and saturday. just unsure of what cmldet to use.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the program you wish to use for the backup.
Below are two options:

- For `robocopy`, see the post
  [ROBOCOPY command to do an incremental backup](https://superuser.com/questions/814102/robocopy-command-to-do-an-incremental-backup).
- For `7Zip`, see the post
  [Incremental backup with 7zip](https://superuser.com/questions/544336/incremental-backup-with-7zip).